# Run x11vnc before user login

Tags: centos, gnome

I'm using Centos 6.9, and I've installed Gnome on it.
Now I'm trying to use x11vnc to remote control it.
The problem is that I want to start the x11vnc without any user login.
I've tried creating a service for it, but it failed because it can't find display:0.

So I've created a startup script in `/etc/xdg/autostart`, but the system seems to not running it.

If I'm trying to run it manually, it works `( awk -F= '/Exec=/{system($2)}' /etc/xdg/autostart/x11vnc.desktop )`

This is my script:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=X11vncstart
GenericName=Run X11vnc
Comment=Run X11vnc 1
Exec=/tmp/x11vncstart.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

UPDATE
To sum it up, thanks to [Hermann](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/67507/hermann) advice, I was able to finally run it.
Another thing that was needed, was that Selinux will allow it to autoprobe tcp for the port.
this is the command for it `chcon -t xserver_exec_t /usr/bin/x11vnc`

UPDATE 2

It works at the greeter screen, but after the login, it closes the x11vnc process.
any ideas?

Comment: Start x11vnc with the display manager, The gui where you enter your user name and password.  What dm are you using? GDM LXDM

Comment: The display manager is GDM

Comment: In response to update 2: You may want to take a look at the x11vnc parameter -reopen, provided your binary is recent enough to support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of `/etc/xdg/autostart` are executed *after* a user logs in graphically. You probably want to start `x11vnc` *with* the display manager (which invokes the login greeter). Depending on your choice of display manager, you need to modify

- `/etc/gdm/Init/:0` for GDM,
- `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsetup` for KDM,
- a (new) file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` (actual file varies) for LightDM

.
I assume you stick to GDM. Invoke `x11vnc` with the `-auth` option. With any luck, `x11vnc -auth guess -display :0 &` should suffice. Do not forget the ampersand, else the display manager waits for `x11vnc` to terminate.

For VNC with LightDM, you can try the internal VNC Server configuration section like this:

```
[VNCServer]
enabled=true
command=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -display :0
```

This content is supposed to go into a new file, e.g. `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/vncserver.conf`.

Comment: Yes, I want x11vnc to start when the login greeter is displayed. In /etc/gdm/Init, i only have a file named default. Do you mean I should invoke x11vnc from it?

Comment: `/etc/gdm/Init/default` applies to all desktops (not only :0). So yes, you can launch x11vnc from there.

Comment: Well, it try to start but failed, this is the error : *** unrecognized option(s) *** [1]  1, but when I run it manually, it works. this is the command /usr/bin/x11vnc  -display :0 -auth /var/run/gdm/$(ls /var/run/gdm | grep $(whoami))/database -forever -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -bg

Comment: ok, figured up the problem, I had 1 at the end of the line, after I've removed it, this error is gone

Comment: 50-disable-log-backup.conf  50-guest-wrapper.conf  50-unity-greeter.conf
50-greeter-wrapper.conf     50-ubuntu.conf         50-xserver-command.conf are the files in lightdm.conf.d/   which one should be edited?  I added your x11vnc command to the 50-xserver-command.conf and rebooted a few times with variations... no response at port 5900 (keeps waiting, waiting on the remote vnc client) until I log in to the box physically via the GUI -  then a rejected by host occurs on the remote vnc client.

Comment: For VNC with LightDM, you can try the internal VNC Server configuration. I updated the original answer.